# I can no longer install anything with pip nor upgrade pip

Tags: python, pip, kivy

Anytime I use `pip install` I get this error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)`

This happens for anything I install or upgrade

*note: it happened after running this `python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip==18.1`

Is there anyway to upgrade/reset/ or reinstall pip?

Comment: why do you install `pip 18.1`? The newest version has number `21.2.x`

Comment: Python 3.10 is very fresh version and some modules may not ready to work with this version - authors need time to recompile them for new Python. Better wait few months and use `3.9` or even `3.8`